# Merge layers (concatenate) in keras

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement this [paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5539-depth-map-prediction-from-a-single-image-using-a-multi-scale-deep-network.pdf) (the model architecture is given below) and have two models- `coarse_model` and `fine_model` which need to be concatenated at the second step of the fine model. However, I am getting an error when I trying to concatenate using the last axis. 
[image]

---

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Merge
from keras.layers.core import Reshape
from keras.layers.merge import Concatenate
from keras import backend as K


# dimensions of our images
#img_width, img_height = 320, 240

img_width, img_height = 304,228


if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

# coarse model
coarse_model = Sequential()
# coarse layer 1
coarse_model.add(Conv2D(96,(11,11),strides=(4,4),input_shape=input_shape,activation='relu'))
coarse_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
# coarse layer 2
coarse_model.add(Conv2D(256,(5,5),activation='relu',padding='same'))
coarse_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
# coarse layer 3
coarse_model.add(Conv2D(384,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
# coarse layer 4
coarse_model.add(Conv2D(384,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
# coarse layer 5
coarse_model.add(Conv2D(256,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
coarse_model.add(Flatten())
# coarse layer 6
coarse_model.add(Dense(4096,activation='relu'))
# coarse layer 7
coarse_model.add(Dense(4070,activation='linear'))

# fine model
fine_model = Sequential()
fine_model.add(Conv2D(63,(9,9),strides=(2,2),input_shape=input_shape,activation='relu'))
fine_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# reshape coarse model to shape of fine model
shape = fine_model.layers[1].output_shape
shape_subset = (shape[1],shape[2])


coarse_model.add(Reshape(shape_subset))
model = Sequential()
model.add(Merge([coarse_model.layers[10],fine_model.layers[1]],mode='concat',concat_axis=3))
```

---

The error given on the last line is:
*** ValueError: "concat" mode can only merge layers with matching output shapes except for the concat axis. Layer shapes: [(None, 74, 55), (None, 74, 55, 63)]

Comment: On what part of your code you get the error? Please add that to your question

Comment: Its the last line. On the merge command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer my own question, changing the shape to

```
shape_subset = (shape[1],shape[2],1)
```

and

```
model.add(Merge([coarse_model.layers[10],fine_model.layers[1]],mode='concat',concat_axis=-1))
```

makes the code work.