# Concatenating two CNN in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to fuse two CNN but when I use concatenate I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vggFace_MM.py", line 57, in <module>
    fuse_layer = concatenate([stream_1, stream_2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/merge.py", line 508, in concatenate
    return Concatenate(axis=axis, **kwargs)(inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 596, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/merge.py", line 283, in call
    return K.concatenate(inputs, axis=self.axis)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 1723, in concatenate
    return tf.concat([to_dense(x) for x in tensors], axis)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1075, in concat
    dtype=dtypes.int32).get_shape(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 669, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 176, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 165, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 367, in make_tensor_proto
    _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 302, in _AssertCompatible
    (dtype.name, repr(mismatch), type(mismatch).__name__))
TypeError: Expected int32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead.
```

Here is my code:

```
stream_1 = vgg_model_1.get_layer('pool5').output
stream_1 = Flatten(name='flatten-1')(stream_1)

stream_2 = vgg_model_2.get_layer('pool5').output
stream_2 = Flatten(name='flatten-2')(stream_2)

fuse_layer = keras.layers.concatenate([stream_1, stream_2])
```

I'm using the VggFace, so vgg_model_1 and vgg_model_2 are the same CNN but each with different inputs.

Comment: Could you mention what do you want to achieve with the concatenation of 2 CNNs? Its preety unclear what you are trying to achieve here, because youve tried concatenating 2 pooling layers which doesnt make sense

Comment: Does it work with this? `fuse_layer = Concatenate()([stream_1,stream_2])` -- Import the concatenation layer `from keras.layers import *`.

Comment: What is your keras version?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to classify face expressions based on certain emotions. In one CNN I have the face and on the other one I have the face but frontalized.

Comment: Are you trying to have a network with 2 heads, one which will have the face expression input, other with face frontalized input and then merge the end values of 2 heads to get one combined output?

Comment: @DanielMöller keras 2.0.6. and I tried our suggestion but it didn't work

Comment: @Anuj Yes, one network receives has input just the face. The second network receives the frontalized face. Then combine both networks and add a softmax and train both networks together.

Comment: Is this `pool5` layer used only once in the VGG model? Or is the input shape of the VGG model made of any `None` dimension other than the first? Print a `model.summary()` and look for the dimensions. Are they like `(None, number, number, number)` or like `(None, None, None, number)`?? Only the first case supports `Flatten` layers.

Comment: @DanielMöller It's the first case.
pool5 
(MaxPooling2D)         (None, 7, 7, 512)
global_max_pooling2d_1 (Glob (None, 512)

Comment: @danielZapata I have not worked with tensor flow, but have worked on torch! so from that experience, i think you need a parallel model and not a sequential, i will still confirm and try to answer the question

Comment: You seem to have nothing wrong there....I have no idea why your tensors are getting is as "message".

Comment: What's the version of TensorFlow? Maybe you can try to update it.

Comment: @Yu-Yang I updated to the latest TensorFlow version and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of using `concatenate` you actually need to use `merge`

Follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787050/merge-layers-concatenate-in-keras) answer for more details.

Follow [this link](https://keras.io/layers/merge/) for more details on `merge`

---

To elaborate more on it, you need to create 2 heads for the models and not the layers of the CNN.
So `Model1` is taking in your FaceEmotion data as input and `Model2` is taking other type of input,

So to create these two heads to give a combined output, you need to create a third model which will merge these 2 models to give a single combined output.

It can be done as follows

```
multi_modal = Sequential()
multi_modal.add(Merge([Model1, Model2], mode='concat'))
```

Comment: Hi Anuj, I already solved it. It had to do with tensorflow version. I updated to the latest and it worked. Thanks for everything